# Incorporate an issued .pem into Websphere 6 keystore

Tags: ssl, websphere

I have an application running on IBM Websphere 6.1. This application must use SSL to communicate with other similar applications used by other (external) entities. I believe I am the only member of this group that is using Websphere. A certificate issuer that others in my group trust, has issued me a '.pem' file. How do I incorporate that into Websphere?

I have tried using ikeyman to open the keystore and truststore used by Websphere for this application but I cannot figure out how to import the .pem file.

Answer (score 1):

you need to incapsulate your pem to pkcs#12 format (use openssl) and then add p12 container to WS configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach is to follow the instructions from this technote: [How to transform PEM and PFX keystore in Public Key Cryptography Standard #12 (PKCS12) keystore](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21280977).